# 122gb of free space needed but partition has 298gb and is empty

Tags: partitioning, mount, samba

I have an old pc set up with ubuntu server 18.04.6 and I've set up an ntfs partition (entire disk) mounted on a directory thats shared via Samba.
The partition hast 298Gb of space (checked with `lsblk`) and its a brand new partition and filesystem (so i assume its free)
I want to use that directory for saving 144gb of files but it wont let me move them because "122gb of free space are needed"
Any idea of whats going on?

Comment: The usual size of files is disk space used by the contents of the file, but but file-system wasted space due to block/inode (ie. you may only store 1 byte of the last block/inode with the remainder wasted).  You've given no specifics on number of files; sizes, types etc nor parameters used in creating NTFS partition - so will it store the require data?   (compress to a tarball to reduce the file-system wasted space if necessary...)..  this is a single reaction; other issues may apply too

Comment: Please edit your question and provide clear reproducible details. Tell us the exact actions needed to reproduce the error and give us the whole error verbatim.  What applications are you using, how are you attempting to copy the files, etc.

Comment: Sounds as if you move data to the mountpoint while the partition is not mounted.